# How can I create an ibm cloud function that deploy from code on a github repo?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-functions

I want to create an action for a trigger in IBM Cloud Functions, but instead of only adding the code in the console, I want the action to deploy from code on a github repository. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Take the code from GitHub" as in "deploy from GitHub"?

Comment: yes, that's what I meant

Comment: You could use the continous delivery service for that. Or if it is just once a script / manual command to fetch the code and deploy it using the CLI.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe (or at least have not seen anywhere in the docs) you can just point the Cloud Functions to a GitHub repo. With that said you could do the following:

Make sure `ibmcloud` CLI is installed and you have the Cloud Functions plugin also installed `ibmcloud plugin install cloud-functions`

1. `ibmcloud login` - You need a valid session in the CLI or use an IBM Cloud API key or a Service ID key that has the right IAM access to deploy to a Cloud Function namespace in IBM Cloud `ibmcloud login --apikey "YOUR_API_KEY"`.
2. `ibmcloud target -r eu-gb` - You need to target the right region where the Cloud Function will live.
3. `ibmcloud target -g test-resource-group` - Once logged in, you need to make sure you target the right resource group where the Cloud Function will be pushed too.

If you are lazy like me then you can roll all 3 of the above commands into 1 like so: `ibmcloud login --apikey "YOUR_API_KEY" -r "eu-gb" -g "test-resource-group"`

4. `ibmcloud functions namespace target test-function-namespace` - Finally, after logging in you need to use the `cloud-functions` plugin to target the right namespace where the Cloud Function will be pushed.

There are multiple ways to deploy the Cloud Function. For example, using the CLI to push the cloud function or using a `manifest.yml` file as a config.

##### Using IBM Cloud CLI

Creating a trigger assuming `test-action` is already created.

```sh
ibmcloud functions trigger create test-trigger --feed test-action
```

##### Using Manifest File

The example below is triggering the `test-action` Cloud Function every 15 minutes using a Cloud Function trigger.

`manifest.yaml`

```yaml
project:
  namespace: _
  packages:
    test-package:
      actions:
        test-action:
          function: ./src/actions/action.js
          runtime: nodejs:12
      
      triggers:
        test-trigger:
          feed: /whisk.system/alarms/interval
          inputs:
            minutes: 15

      rules:
        rile-test-trigger:
          trigger: test-trigger
          action: test-action
```

To deploy this you essentially just:

```sh
ibmcloud functions deploy -m ./manifest.yaml
```

Both options can essentially be wired into a CD tool like Travis or Jenkins and can automatically deploy latest changes to the Cloud from GitHub.